# How to properly query Datastore with Python? - issue with the basics

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

As a beginner in Python and App Engine I once again have to ask for your assistance. For some time I've been working with the book "Code in the Cloud" to learn the very basics of using App Engine. The thing is I have not been very successful so far. While most of the issues I have had stemmed from UTF-8 encoding/decoding, this time I have problems with making queries to Datastore.

To learn the basics I recreated the code for a simple chat service available in chapter IV of the aforesaid book. The key elements are:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import datetime

from google.appengine.ext import db

#START: ChatMessage
class ChatMessage(db.Model):
    user = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    timestamp = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    message = db.TextProperty(required=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s (%s): %s" % (self.user, self.timestamp, self.message)
#END: ChatMessage
```

Above, I defined the datamodel for a message

```
class ChatRoomPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
        self.response.out.write("""
           <html>
             <head>
               <title>AppEngine Chat Room</title>
             </head>
             <body>
               <h1>Welcome to AppEngine Chat Room</h1>
               <p>(Current time is %s)</p>
           """ % (datetime.datetime.now()))
        messages = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * From ChatMessage ORDER BY time")
        for msg in messages:
            self.response.out.write("<p>%s</p>" % msg)
        self.response.out.write("""
           <form action="/talk" method="post"> 
          <div><b>Name:</b> 
           <textarea name="name" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea></div>
           <p><b>Message</b></p>
           <div><textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea></div>
           <div><input type="submit" value="Send ChatMessage"/></div>
           </form>
         </body>
       </html>
       """)
# END: MainPage
```

In the block above I create UI and performe a GQL query for data I posted.

Lastly:

```
class ChatRoomPoster(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        chatter = self.request.get("name")
        msgtext = self.request.get("message")
        msg = ChatMessage(user=chatter, message=msgtext)
        msg.put()
        self.redirect('/')
```

I create the handler to send the collected data into Datastore.

Having consulted the book line by line, as well as Google tutorial, and a number of threads on this website, I still can't figure out, why the code does not work properly. Basically, the chat won't display past messages. My guess is I am doing something wrong with accessing the stored data, as the program does not throw any exception - I am missing an identifier or something like that. Perhaps I am again missing something very obvious.

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your title doesn't provide any useful information.  Apparently your question is "how to query the datastore?"  Or something like that.  Please be sure your question is (a) obvious and (b) summarized by your title.  Please **update** your question to be more clear.

Comment: Also, please search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+gae+query These questions are all related.  One (or more) of them may already answer your question.

Comment: @ S Lott. As you suggested, I corrected the title. I already browsed through threads with similar issues. Nonetheless, I fail to see what I did wrong here. Again, the issue maybe very simple (probably is), but without some guidance I don't think I will come up with solution.

Comment: @Mathias: Search is the guidance.  You're not the first person to ask this question.  "Browsing through the threads" sounds like you haven't actually read any of the 100's of related questions.  I would (again) suggest actually reading all of the first hundred questions in detail.  The more code you see -- in the other questions -- the more you'll understand.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is:

```
    messages = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * From ChatMessage ORDER BY time")
```

but your datastore model doesn't have a `time` property, it has a `timestamp` property. Attempting to order by a property that isn't on any entities will always return an empty resultset.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop over the messages, 'msg' is a datastore object.  You need to reference a specific attribute (ie msg.message).

```
for msg in messages:
    self.response.out.write("<p>%s</p>" % msg.message)
```

Comment: It's fine to refer to just `msg` since the `ChatMessage` class has `__str__` method whose result seems to be expected here.